JLink is non-existent
Gradle build of an Android project in Intellij fails with

jlink executable C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.1.2\jbr\bin\jlink.exe does not exist

That is true, jlink.exe does not exist in that directory. The Android project was created by importing an existing Google Developer codelab project from GitHub.
This issue has been asked on StackExchange, but not fully answered.
Duplicate Question
One of the answers is that jlink is not included in the jbr (JetBrainsRuntime) that comes with Intellij, where it does come with Android Studio. There is a link to the release page of jbr on Github, but does not describe how to deploy that to my Intellij.
How do I import jbr into my Intellij environment?
The Windows version is available as a tar file.
Answer with link to JBR
